# What is the difference between dependency injection and dependency look up?

Tags: spring

What is Dependency look up?Could someone please clarify these two concepts.

Answer (score 11):

Dependency lookup is when the object itself is trying to find a dependency, such as:

```java
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
MyBean bean = applicationContext.getBean("myBean")
```

Here, the class itself is initializing the `ApplicationContext` through an XML, and it is searching in the context for the bean called `myBean` in the `ApplicationContext`

The Dependency injection is when a property is automatically bound when an instance is initialized. For example:

in the `application-context.xml`, we have one line which initialize the bean and another to initialize the object of, let's say, `MyClass`:

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="org.mypackage.MyBean"/>
<bean id="myClass" class="org.mypackage.MyClass"/>
```

Then in `MyClass`, you have something like:

```java
@Component
public class MyClass{

  @Autowired
  MyBean myBean;

  // ...
}
```

In this case, you have specified that two instances of two beans are initialized. And the `myClass` bean has a property called `myBean` which is already initialized due to the injection

Answer (score 9):

Since @Michael Zucchetta explained what is the difference in the context of Spring, I'll try to give you a more general explanation. The main difference between the two approaches is "who is responsible for retrieving the dependencies".

Usually, in DI(dependency injection) your component isn't aware of the DI container and dependencies "automagically" appear (e.g. you just declare some setters/ constructor parameters and the DI container fills them for you).

In, DL (dependency lookup) you have to specifically ask for what you need. What this means in practice is that you have a dependency on the context (in spring the Application context) and retrieve whatever you need from it.

You can take a look at [ServiceLocator vs DependencyInjection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection) by M. Fowler for a better explanaition, but I'll give you a quote:

> The key difference is that with a Service Locator every user of a service has a dependency to the locator. The locator can hide dependencies to other implementations, but you do need to see the locator. So the decision between locator and injector depends on whether that dependency is a problem.
>
> Using dependency injection can help make it easier to see what the component dependencies are. With dependency injector you can just look at the injection mechanism, such as the constructor, and see the dependencies. With the service locator you have to search the source code for calls to the locator. Modern IDEs with a find references feature make this easier, but it's still not as easy as looking at the constructor or setting methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, Does "Service Locator" and "Dependency Lookup" the same concept?

Answer (score 5):

**Dependency lookup** is more traditional approach:

- component has to ask for dependency reference from JNDI registry

We can achieve this by the way of two methods:

1. Dependency Pull

```java
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
SimpleBean mr = ctx.getBean("renderer", SimpleBean.class);
```

2. Contextualized Dependency Lookup (lookup is pulled from directly from container, not from registry). Component has to implement specific interface in order to be able execute lookup

```java
public interface Container {
   Object dependencyLookup(String key);
}

public class CDL implements Container {
   private Dependency dependency;

   @Override
   public void performLookup(Container container) {
       this.dependency = (Dependency) container.dependencyLookup("myDependency");
   }
}
```

**Dependency injection** is more counterintuitive (but more flexible , scalable):

- dependencies are injected into component

There are two ways to do this by:

1. Constructor
2. Setter Dependency Injection.